# Updating text in a QLineEdit text box generated from a for loop reading a dict

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I have 2 QLineEdit boxes generated using a for loop that are pulling the names and initial text values from a dictionary. The code I have updates the dictionary values just fine and it generates the edit boxes correctly. What I am having problems with is actually updating the values on the gui for the user to see. I am using pyside2 and python 3.7.2 on windows 10 pro.

If I 'hard code' the QLineEdit boxes it works as expected using  `self.display1.setText("asdf")` . The way I'm generating the inputs I'm unable to figure out how to do that other than updating the dictionary value that is assigned to the text of the edit box. I've tried calling `update()` and `repaint()` at time of button click and after the values in the dictionary are modified. I've also tried redefining the widgets by calling a function that remade the inputs and did `.addWidget()`. This, as expected, generated new ones below the edit boxes that were already generated. However, the text in the boxes were correct.

This is the loop that generates the inputs

```
for val, key in self.inputDict.items():
    self.inputs = QLineEdit(key, self)
    self.inputs.setText(key)
    self.vertCol.addWidget(self.inputs)
```

The relevant dict: `self.inputDict = {"display1": "", "display2": ""}`.

This is the loop that generates the buttons(it's in a loop because this is is just 1 function of this program I'm building, other buttons roll different sided die)

```
for key, val in self.buttonDict.items():
    self.buttons = QPushButton(key, self)
    self.buttons.setToolTip("D20 die rolled: 1-10=low, 11-20=high; Coin Flip: 0=Heads(Good) 1=Tails(Bad)")
    self.buttons.clicked.connect(partial(self.handlehlgb))
    self.vertCol.addWidget(self.buttons)
```

The relevant button dict `self.buttonDict = {"High-Low-Good-Bad": "hlgb"}`

And this is the function that I'm trying to get to work:

```
    def handlehlgb(self):
        self.coinFlip = randrange(2)
        self.rollD20 = randint(1, 20)
        if self.coinFlip <= 0:
            self.inputDict.update({'display1': 'Good'})
            print(self.inputDict["display1"])
        else:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'Bad'})
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
        if self.rollD20 <= 10:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'Low'})
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
        else:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'High'})
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
```

It's meant to display Good/Bad determined off of a 'coin flip' and High/Low based off of a D20 die roll.

I'm expecting it to update the display on the GUI, but it doesn't. It will print the correct value of the displays in the console. Here's a pastebin of what I'm working with: https://pastebin.com/H6LAnbnH

I'm relatively new with python and especially with pyside/pyqt. So any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood, but it seems that if you simply add a setText after rolling the dice:

```
self.inputDict.update({'display1': 'Good'})
self.inputs.setText(self.inputDict["display2"])
```

the text is updated in the QLineEdit.

Then you may want to make `self.inputs` a dictionary, so you can change both QLineEdits:

```
self.inputs = {}
for val, key in self.inputDict.items():
    self.inputs[key] = QLineEdit(key, self)

...

self.inputDict.update({'display1': 'Good'})
self.inputs['display1'].setText(self.inputDict['display1'])
```

(wait ... now that I copy-paste your code, I see that you wrote `val,key in ...`, when you probably wanted it to be `key,val in ...`). Could it be simply that?

[edit] 
here's what it becomes with both ideas:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.buttonDict = {"High-Low-Good-Bad": "hlgb"}
        self.inputDict = {"display1": "", "display2": ""}
        self.vertCol = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.inputs = {}
        for key, val in self.inputDict.items():
            self.inputs[key] = QLineEdit(key, self)
            self.inputs[key].setText(val)
            print("Key - " + key)
            print("Val - " + val)
            self.vertCol.addWidget(self.inputs[key])

        for key, val in self.buttonDict.items():
            self.buttons = QPushButton(key, self)
            self.buttons.setToolTip("D20 die rolled: 1-10=low, 11-20=high; Coin Flip: 0=Heads(Good) 1=Tails(Bad)")
            self.buttons.clicked.connect(partial(self.handlehlgb))
            #self.buttons.clicked.connect(self.inputs.update())
            self.vertCol.addWidget(self.buttons)

    def handlehlgb(self):
        self.coinFlip = randrange(2)
        self.rollD20 = randint(1, 20)
        if self.coinFlip <= 0:
            self.inputDict.update({'display1': 'Good'})
            self.inputs['display1'].setText('Good')
            print(self.inputDict["display1"])
        else:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'Bad'})
            self.inputs['display1'].setText('Bad')
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
        if self.rollD20 <= 10:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'Low'})
            self.inputs['display2'].setText('Low')
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
        else:
            self.inputDict.update({'display2': 'High'})
            self.inputs['display2'].setText('High')
            print(self.inputDict["display2"])
```

Comment: `self.inputs['display1'].setText(self.inputDict['display1'])` returns a TypeError `TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' object is not subscriptable`

So I tired it without the first set of brackets and it updates the gui now, just only the bottom text area.

Also I've changed around key and val, same behavior.

Comment: Making inputs a dictionary results in this error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'setText'`

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know what I missed when modifying to what you suggested, but what you put there works 100%!!!